# "I hate change"

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, english-to-japanese

How would you say "I hate change" in Japanese? I feel like 「私は変更を憎みます」 would just sound like a bad google translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (abstract) "change", 変化 *henka* seems to be the better choice.

For "hate" (or "dislike"), there are also

- 嫌【いや】です
- 嫌い【きらい】です
- 大嫌い【だいきらい】です

憎む is a "bigger" word, like "despise" or "detest". Since "hate" is quite a simple word, I would go with

> 変化が大嫌い（だ・です）

Comment: Might 変革 also work?

Comment: @user27280 変革 refers to a good but drastic change. 変革が嫌い works, but it means someone dislikes even good changes.

Comment: Thanks. I was conflating it with 'progress', which can have a negative connotation to those who prefer the status quo.